# Out of range value for column MySQL for a Tinyint

Tags: mysql

So I have this issue with `tinyint(2)` **unsigned** column on MySQL 5.1.

The last time I checked, `tinyint` **unsigned** was accepting up to a value of 255, cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html

Now, when I try to update this column for all entries, by adding a randomly generated value, between 100 and 160 as:

```
UPDATE composition SET range = range + (FLOOR(100 + RAND() * 60));
```

I get a smart message telling me that I have an Out Of range error:

> Out of range value for column 'range' at row 1660

How is that even possible?

Comment: Are you sure it is unsigned? try 127 and then 128...

Comment: can you confirm what is the max value it will accept before going out of range? What happens if you set it to a negative?

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT MAX(range) FROM composition`?

Comment: range can already have 200 for example and the you are adding to it 100 minimum. it becomes 300...

Comment: The maximum value after I checked was of 67. So 67 + 160 (the worst case scenario) = 225. Still under 255.

Comment: Narrow down the problem with verifiable values. Don't randomly add something to something to trigger some unknown maximum value. As suggested above, insert 127, then 128, and/or further increase step by step to figure out which values start being problematic!

Comment: @Shotgun How many times you run this update?

Comment: I figured it out. on my computer it was on non-strict mode so it silently converted it the maximum value. Or another environment it was on strict mode, which made any value exceeding 255 to throw an error. The problem was that the UPDATE was ran twice by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Just verify existing range value and then update range.

```
UPDATE `composition`
SET `range`=`range`+FLOOR(100 + RAND() * 60)
WHERE `range` < 95
```